# How to show that a set is not convex in the following problem?

Tags: complex-numbers, convex-analysis

I need to show that $x^2>y$ is not convex where $z=x+iy$. I know what it means to be convex but I cannot figure out how to show it rigorously. A methodological answer would be helpful.

Comment: I need to show it rigorously, picture doesnt suffice, I have indicated that

Comment: You seem to be mistaken about what constitutes a rigorous proof. EpsilonDelta's answer is formally correct and complete, and should be accepted as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It suffices to give a counter example. Take $z_1=2+i$ and $z_2=-2+i$. If the set is convex then $(z_1+z_2)/2$ should also be in the set. But, $(z_1+z_2)/2=0+i$ which is not in the set.

Comment: Can you write an actual proof?

Comment: Why this isn't an actual proof??

Comment: a formal proof, I mean

Comment: A proof for what? Counterexamples do not require proofs.

Comment: This is a formal proof. In order to show that some statement is false it is suffices to give a counter example. Try to understand it!

Comment: I am supposed to show it is not convex. It doesnt say "Show it is convex" and you bring a counterexample that it is not

Comment: @JennieDurham  How do you show that "Not all integers are even?"

Comment: I have proven that it is NOT convex

Comment: @JennieDurham: EpsilonDelta is correct. *This is a proof*. It is *exactly* what you have requested. Perhaps you need to do a bit of study on proofs alongside convex analysis. +1, EpsilonDelta.

Answer (score 1):

Take $z_1=1+0\cdot i=1$ and $z_2=-1+0\cdot i=-1$. Since $1^2=(-1)^2>0$ they belong to the set. If the set were convex $\frac12z_1+\frac12z_2$ would belong to it too, but $\frac12z_1+\frac12z_2=0+0\cdot i$ and $0^2>0$ is false. Therefore, the set is not convex. Q.E.D.